# How to run selenium script with fixed time and how to host it

Tags: python, selenium, schedule

I created a script for automating a system. But I am stuck with the hosting the script and with the time. Lets discuss about the time first.

Here is my code:

```
from ray import SMSBot
import schedule

with SMSBot() as sms:
    def execute():
        sms.go_to_dashboard("https://sms.rayadvertising.com/login")
        sms.login_to_dashboard("*****", "*****")
        sms.find_number_section()
    
schedule.every(1).minute.do(execute())
schedule.every(20).minute.do(execute())
schedule.every(2).hour.do(execute())
schedule.every(12).hour.do(execute())
schedule.every(24).hour.do(execute())
schedule.every(26).hour.do(execute())
```

I tried this code. But I am afraid of taking this script on deployment.

What I want:

I want the script run after 5 min then 20 min then 2 hour then 12 hour then 24 hour then 26 hour.
how can I do that? Is my code ok?

second thing is I want to host it. Where and how can I host this script. I am running ubuntu in laptop I know I can run the script in my laptop but its not possible to keep running the laptop whole day.

Is there any help for me?